# Как на c# построчно проверить на содержание в переменной любой строки из файла?

Tags: c#

Нужно проверять на наличие в текста стоп-слов из списка, если слова нет, то записывать в файл.

```
StreamReader words = new StreamReader(@"stop_words.txt");
                    while (!words.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        //string word = words.ReadLine();
                        string word1 = "Уважаемый";
                        if (CleanedString.Contains(word1) == false)
                        {
                            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter($"{i}.txt"))
                                {
                                    sw.WriteLine(title + "\n" + CleanedString);
                                }
                            
                        }
                    }
                    words.Close();
```

```
StreamReader words = new StreamReader(@"stop_words.txt");
                    while (!words.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        string word = words.ReadLine();
                        //string word1 = "Уважаемый";
                        if (CleanedString.Contains(word.Trim()) == false)
                        {
                            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter($"{i}.txt"))
                                {
                                    sw.WriteLine(title + "\n" + CleanedString);
                                }
                            
                        }
                    }
                    words.Close();
```

stop_words.txt вида:

```
Уважаемый
лалала
```

Первый код отрабатывает верно, второй код игнорирует проверку. В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: `но команда действие() не срабатывает` замените псевдокод на реальный код. `Нужно проверять` вы проверяете, а дальше что? Если слово найдено, что сделать? Следующее искать? Если не найдено, то что? При нахождении первого слова, надо остановиться или продолжить поиск? Посчитать количество слов? Вопрос для Ванги?

Comment: А почему `Contains(...) == false`? Это условие **не нахождения**. Действие будет производится, если слово не найдено.

Comment: Дописал код вместо действие(). Если убрать этот код проверки, то все выполняется нормально. Попробовал поменять false на true, все равно не работает.

Comment: Вы почти ни на один из выше поставленных вопросов не ответили. Опишите конкретную задачу, не жалейте букв, они бесплатные. Исправьте текст вопроса.

Comment: А что у вас в `i`? Вы уверены, что это не срабатывает, а то может перезаписывает существующий файл, а вы не замечаете. Проще всего пройти отладкой по строкам и всё понять.

Comment: Переформулировал вопрос, файл читает, строки из него получает, но по ним почему-то происходит проверка, когда по объявленной строке все работает корректно.

Comment: А слово в том же регистре содержится в `CleanedString`? И в той же кодировке? Попробуйте выводить на консоль `word` и `CleanedString` перед проверкой. Вплоть до того, что в одном из слов могут был английские буквы вместо русских местами.

Comment: Да, с регистром все отлично. Как вариант в файл записал слова в обоих регистрах.

Comment: Выведите на консоль. Скопируйте что вывелось в вопрос, посмотрим, сравним. А так то достаточно одного регистра для хранения, а вот при самом сравнении приводить к одному регистру.